# Make a caption on a copper layer in Eagle

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

Read all the internet but cannot find how to make a caption on the copper "ratsnest" (either top or bottom) in Eagle.

I want to make it "negative", i. e. no copper where letters are supposed to be. Now when I add the caption to the top or bottom layer, Eagle makes a no-copper square and puts a copper caption inside (copper is brown):

[image]

But I want it to be like this:

[image]

The question is: how to do that?

Tried to put the caption on the keepout and restrict layers. In case I set it to the "restrict" layer, just the empty box is drawn without any copper including text itself:

[image]

In case I set it to the "keepout" layer, nothing happens:

[image]

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: copper keepout area.

Comment: @MarcusMüller as I wrote, it does not work. Eagle just fills it with copper. Even tried to make a box connected to the ground plane and to put caption on it - no effect, after ratsnest it became filled with copper.

Comment: ah sorry, in eagle that layer is called "tRestrict". Draw text or polygons on that layer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Marcus, I appreciate your help, thank you for it so much, but I tried that and wrote about that in the question.

Comment: ah, missed the "Tried to put … and restrict", sorry. What does it do instead, when you put text in tRestrict? The same seems unlikely.

Comment: Added a brief explanation

Comment: @MarcusMüller just an empty box without copper and text.

Comment: huh. What happens when you draw a graphical line on the restrict layer instead? Is that properly left clean?

Comment: @MarcusMüller drc shows no error. Where can I check this?

Comment: @MarcusMüller in case I draw the line the result is - the copper line in the no-copper block

Comment: @MarcusMüller sorry, my mistake, empty space without copper (

Comment: so, that works. Hm, the workaround I could think of would consist of converting the text to lines, but I don't know how tempting you find that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Have no idea how to do that. You mean to draw all letters I need with lines?

Comment: Haven't used Eagle in ages, but I was assuming one could import drawings from external files into layers

Comment: @MarcusMüller ah, well, sure it can. Will try and report back

Comment: @MarcusMüller cannot make it working, it's awful

Answer (score 1):

TL:DR
Same problem , different tool, 4 ways

Adapt to your tool

1. Polygon method
2. Bitmap Import
3. DXF Import
4. Custom TrueType Font

Polygon method

Home | Fill - a filled polygonal shape with any number of vertices

Home | Solid Region - a simple filled rectangular shape

Home | Polygon Pour - a filled polygonal shape that will repour around other objects ... Like text

https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-89106/l/adding-logos-to-your-pcb-layout

You may find better answer already in Eagle forums...  no more time here

You are pretty good and much better than I ...
 "if you read all the internet"